# How to interpolate 2D function over a large curvilinear mesh?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cgal

I have some surface data given as `x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh`.

`x_mesh` and `y_mesh` were generated from steps by longitude and latitude on a geotiff (so, their shapes are equal and regular but steps by x and y are not).

`z_mesh` is the height from tangential plane to Earth ellipsoid at the center of map.

I can easily plot the surface with `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh)`. It works.

Now I want to set a line by mouse and somehow take a Z profile under this line. I need some interpolator to make xy --> z, but don't know which one to use.

I tried to do this:

```
scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh)
```

But it gives me an error: `OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate`

Don't you have any ideas how to interpolate such data?

P.S. The geotiff is not very big, it is 6K x 6K pixels. And I see that `pcolormesh` somehow interpolates the color value between pixels if I zoom in.

[image]

Comment: if `x` and `y` steps are not regular, `interp2d` isn't going to help you much.  Have you tried [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)?  I'm fairly certain that despite the name it can interpolate arbitrary points.